# Pandas Pivot Table Filtering Based on Criteria

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

So I have a pivot_table, basically a multilevel df, that I want to filter by a couple of parameters.

colum dtypes:

```
Report          object
Owner           object
Description     object
TimeToRun       object
FacilityName    object
Base Report     object
```

pd func:

```
pv=pd.pivot_table(test, index = ['TimeToRun'], columns = ['FacilityName'], values = ['Base Report'], aggfunc='count', fill_value=0)
```

pv.columns

```
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'Base Report'], [u'Roseville', u'Sacramento', u'South Sacramento']],
       labels=[[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2]],
       names=[None, u'FacName'])
```

My thing is that I want to filter the resulting df by the second level values, i want to filter it so that any values that are greater than count of 2 are indexed. So far, here is my soln, but this does not work in a dynamic situation, where the values in the second level `[u'Roseville', u'Sacramento', u'South Sacramento']` are different(length of the columns).

Here is my query:

```
query = pv[(pv[pv.columns[0]]>2) | (pv[pv.columns[1]]>2)| (pv[pv.columns[2]]>2)]
```

here is how the pivot_table looks like, rendered in excel:

```
    Base Report 
FacilityName        Santa Clara Santa Teresa
TimeToRun       
2018-03-28 07:00:00    4    0
2018-03-28 07:01:00    4    0
2018-03-28 07:02:00    6    0
2018-03-28 07:03:00    5    0
2018-03-28 09:05:00    0    3
2018-03-28 09:15:00    0    6
2018-03-28 14:45:00    3    0
2018-03-28 17:15:00    0    5
2018-03-28 19:10:00    0    3
2018-03-28 19:15:00    0    4
```

I am convinced there is a better way, please show me how. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

How about iterating over the columns and dropping those that do not meet the count criteria?

```
for col in pv.columns:
    if not any(pv[col] > 2):
        pv.drop(col,axis=1,inplace=True)
```

Comment: what you are doing here is that your dropping the entire column. Also this does not result in a queried df, it results in a patched up index. For example if from above data, we dropped "3-28-2018 19:15:.00" for Santa Clara because it didn't meet the criteria then that would also get rid of Santa Teresa which meets the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
pv[pv[('Base Report')]>2].dropna(axis=0,how='all')
```

you can also apply it in place or just return it...thanks though!

Result below, note that the blanks are 0 values:

```
None    Base Report Base Report
FacilityName    Santa Clara Santa Teresa
TimeToRun       
2018-03-29 07:00:00 4.0 
2018-03-29 07:01:00 4.0 
2018-03-29 07:02:00 6.0 
2018-03-29 07:03:00 5.0 
2018-03-29 09:05:00     3.0
2018-03-29 09:15:00     6.0
2018-03-29 14:45:00 3.0 
2018-03-29 17:15:00     5.0
2018-03-29 19:10:00     3.0
2018-03-29 19:15:00     4.0
```